# Brother printer stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04 - again

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I got a Brother DCP-135c printer and after reading through most, if not every, post about Brother printers trying to solve my issues on 20.04, I managed to get my Brother printer working! It took me ages. I had a clean and fresh 20.04 install and used the Brother drivers via the Brother site.

[image: printer installed with cups]

The printer is recognised and the system sends the data to the printer and it goes idle! I have no idea what happened and why it is not working anymore. It just worked fine yesterday.

I installed the LPR printer driver (deb package) and the CUPSwrapper printer driver (deb package) - even several times! Would this be an issue? Is there a way to remove all previous drivers?

I checked via http://localhost:631/ and everything seems fine there too. As I said before, I tried most things and read through most posts on the web regarding Brother printers not printing. It's odd, as it worked just fine and then stopped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am going mad here and about to throw this darn printer out the window.

Comment: One option: Return the printer. Do not support manufacturers and vendors who falsely claim Linux compatibility. You have a choice.

Comment: @user535733  it does seem like something is not quite right with printers and Ubuntu 20.04.  Quite a few posts on here and other forums mention printers work well with 18.04 and before, but problems with them working with 20.04.  Have problem with a Pantum printer on 20.04 that work well before(not asking for help now).

Comment: I managed to get it working for now - I went to the brother site and used their driver installer - I had issues installing tz files before, so after I managed to install it worked. Let's see for how long! Thank you for the support guys!

Comment: @Hagendaz what did you use for URI?

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours on this until I realized I had to first ensure my printer was recognized by my computer (yeah, I know).

Here's what worked for me (do this if you ping your printer's IP address and it is not found):

1. Reset modem (wait 1 minute)
2. Disconnect power and cable from modem and wait 10 seconds
3. Reconnect
4. After wifi comes back on:
   -Turn off printer
5. Turn on printer
6. In Terminal:
   -Ping 192.168.4.25

If you get data that does not say “not found” or something like that
You’re golden!

7. Add printer via settings/Printers
8. When selecting driver, there may be 2 that match the printer:
   If so, select the one that says “appsocket/jetdirect…”